# How to temporally hide the Navigation Bar from Firefox extension?

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I'm developing an extension for Firefox for Android and I need to programatically open a new tab with no navigation bar. I know I can do it with JS with `window.open("http://www.google.com", "mywindow", "location=0,toolbar=0");` but this time I need to disable it another way, because the tab is being opened via [loadURI](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Firefox_for_Android/API/BrowserApp/loadURI). So, the thing is, how can I change the toolbar visibility once loadURI was executed?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need to clarify i dont understand what exactly youre trying to do

Comment: @Noitidart I need to open a new tab with no navigation bar. I am developing an extension for Firefox for Android

Comment: So whenever a specific  tab is focused you want the navbar to hide?

Comment: Yep, just the one I opened programatically

Comment: I dont know how to do it in android. IRC might be a good idea, share the solution once you find it.

Comment: But this is not Android it-s Firefox for Android. Do you know how to do it in Desktop_ It should be a good starting for me

Comment: On desktop: `document.getElementById('nav-bar').style.display = 'none'`, or use `navigator-toolbox` to get all so: `document.getElementById('navigator-toolbox').style.display = 'none'`

Comment: Thanks you!! I will try something with that and let you know! :)

Comment: Cool, definitely let me know I hope to get into addons on firefox for mobile/android one day.

Comment: Hi @Noitidart I tryed a lot of thing but didn't work at all because there is no XUL in FF for Android. So I just solved it by calling fullscreen mode:

Comment: window.BrowserApp.selectedBrowser.contentWindow.fullScreen = true;

Where window is the chrome window, not the object window

Comment: Cool share, no XUL on Android is informative

Answer (score 1):

You have to make browser go to full screen mode to achieve that.

For mobile FF you have to create manifest and at there:

```
"fullscreen": "true"
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Apps/Build/Manifest#fullscreen

Comment: but this is for Open Web Apps, not for extensions :( Or there is a way to emulate this?

Answer (score 1):

I tryed a lot of things I fount over Internet but no success because there is no XUL in FF for Android. So I just solved it by calling fullscreen mode:

```
window.BrowserApp.selectedBrowser.contentWindow.fullScreen = true;
```

Where window is the chrome window, not the object window

Comment: Did you find a way to make the navigation bar always stay? Im getting into android addons and was hoping to start with something simple like this.

Comment: Hi @Noitidart I just used fullscreenmode, but is not stable yet in Firefox for Android (even nightly)

Comment: If you want the visibility to stay, maybe you can force the config of the browser or check window.BrowserApp.selectedBrowser.contentWindow.fullScreen to turn it true

Comment: Thanks I'm getting seriously into some Android developement, especially with js-ctypes for my screenshot addon. Any collaboration or chats you can do on mozIRC or stackoverflow would be really appreciated! If you can work on and come up with a solution to make an addon to make the nav bar stay in non-fullscreen mode that would be super appreciated! So I can focus on the screenshot stuff as I know you were also looking for that.

Comment: @Noitidart I'm not on mobile anymore! But I can suggest you to download and use Nightly in Android, the las version I used (41) they solved some fullscreen problems, like the menu been always visible. I don't know what you call "nav bar", but maybe is the same and it's just matter of time to arrive to stable editions of the browser (Beta didn't have it 3 weeks ago) So --> https://nightly.mozilla.org/

Comment: they = mozilla team ;)

Comment: cool stuff, Im actually never on mobile, im just doing it for the users. Would be awesome if you had time if you can join me in that effort :)